# two nested list make one list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, zip, list-comprehension

Here are 2 list below

```
list1 = [[1,2],[3,4]]
list2 = [[11,22],[33,44]]
```

I tried to this

```
output =list(tuple(zip(i, j)) for i, j in zip(list1, list2))
```

But my output is not as desired.

```
[((1, 11), (2, 22)), ((3, 33), (4, 44))]
```

I want to one to one correspondence such as output like

```
[(1,11),(2,22),(3,33),(4,44)]
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Your original code generates a list of tuples of tuples because you have an outer `list()`, a `tuple()`, and `zip()` which generates the actual tuples -- you want to get rid of that `tuple()` in the middle and instead just have a single list comprehension that captures all the tuples produced by `zip(i, j)`.

You can do this by putting two `for` statements in the comprehension (not wrapping either in a `tuple()` call):

```
>>> list1 = [[1,2],[3,4]]
>>> list2 = [[11,22],[33,44]]
>>> [z for i, j in zip(list1, list2) for z in zip(i, j)]
[(1, 11), (2, 22), (3, 33), (4, 44)]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this as well with one for loop:

```
k=[]
for x,y in enumerate(list1):
    k.append(tuple(zip(y,list2[x]))[0])
    k.append(tuple(zip(y,list2[x]))[1])

#k
[(1, 11), (2, 22), (3, 33), (4, 44)]
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using `Numpy`

Try this numpy solution -

```
import numpy as np

np.array(list1+list2).reshape(2,-1).T.tolist()
```

```
[[1, 11], [2, 22], [3, 33], [4, 44]]
```

---

If you need the internal lists to be tuples, do this variation.

```
import numpy as np

list(map(tuple, np.array(list1+list2).reshape(2,-1).T))
```

```
[(1, 11), (2, 22), (3, 33), (4, 44)]
```

Answer (score -1):

#python program for intersection of two nested lists
import itertools
import functools

def GCI(lst1, lst2):

```
temp1 = functools.reduce(lambda a, b: set(a).union(set(b)), lst1)
temp2 = functools.reduce(lambda a, b: set(a).union(set(b)), lst2)
 
lst3 = [list(set(a).intersection(set(b)))
       for a, b in itertools.product(lst1, lst2)
       if len(set(a).intersection(set(b))) != 0]
 
lst3.extend([x] for x in temp1.symmetric_difference(temp2))
 
return lst3
```

Hope it helps.....